# Using MatExpansionPannel for Mrnu items and sub menu Items

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, frontend

I'm using mat expansion pannel, Of Angular Material, for making Menubar and their submenus. I have achieved that target which I have thought but the problem is whenever I chose the submenu it switched to the other page but the expansion panel get close.

Is there any possibility to make the expansion panel remain open and the submenu remains active unless we are on that page?

```xml
<ul class="menubar-container" [class.toggle-menu]="toggleNav">
    <mat-accordion>

        <li
        class="menu-item"
        *ngFor="let menu of menus"
        >
            <mat-expansion-panel
            (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
            (closed)="panelOpenState = false"
            >
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>
                        <span class="material-icons menu-icon-wrapper">
                            {{ menu.menuIcon }}
                        </span>
                        <p class="link-text">
                            {{ menu.menuItemName }}
                        </p>
                    </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <div class="submenu-items" *ngFor="let submenu of submenus">
                    <a
                        *ngIf="isEng == true"
                        (click)="
                        Redirect(submenu.formPath, submenu.moduleID, submenu.desc_En, submenu.desc_Ar)
                        "
                        class="submenu-item-link pl-4"
                    >
                        <span class="material-icons submenu-icon">
                            keyboard_arrow_right
                        </span>
                        {{ submenu.desc_En }}
                    </a>
                    <a
                        *ngIf="isEng == false"
                        (click)="
                        Redirect(submenu.formPath, submenu.moduleID, submenu.desc_En, submenu.desc_Ar)
                        "
                        class="submenu-item-link pr-4"
                    >
                        <span class="material-icons submenu-icon">
                            keyboard_arrow_left
                        </span>
                        {{ submenu.desc_Ar }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
        </li>

    </mat-accordion>
</ul>
```

Please Let me know if someone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$event.preventDefault()` to your click handler:

```
(click)="Redirect(submenu.formPath, submenu.moduleID, submenu.desc_En, submenu.desc_Ar); $event.preventDefault()"
```